# Convert date column in dataframe to unix python

Tags: python, dataframe, date, unix

I would like to convert a date column in a Dataframe to unixtime in a new column.

```
Index                  Date Second     Measurement      
0     0 2020-02-24 10:52:38  0.000  0.001155460021
1     1 2020-02-24 10:52:39  0.109  0.001124729984
2     2 2020-02-24 10:52:40  0.203  0.001119069988
```

I tried a lot, but always get an error. This does not work:

```
laser['unixtime'] = laser['Date'].arrow.timestamp()
laser['unixtime'] = laser['Date'].timestamp()
laser['unixtime'] = time.mktime(laser['Date'].timetuple())
```

Can anyone help me out?

greets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution with two examples (one when the Date column is a string and one when it is not).

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timezone
# Suppress scientific notation in Pandas
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: f"{x:.0f}")

df = pd.DataFrame()
df["Date"] = pd.date_range(start='2014-08-01 09:00', freq='H', periods=3, tz='Europe/Berlin')
df["DateUnix"] = df.Date.map(lambda x: x.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp())
df


df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Date": ["2020-02-24 10:52:38"]})
# Convert from object to datetime
df2.Date = pd.to_datetime(df2.Date)
df2["DateUnix"] = df2.Date.map(lambda x: x.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp())
df2
```

Comment: Nice! It works, thanks a lot ;-)
How can I change the timezone to CET? "tzinfo=timezone.cet" or 'tzinfo=Europe/Berlin' does not work

Comment: What error does it throw? What `datetime` and `pandas` version are you using? You could try to upgrade to the latest versions of these packages and see if works.

Comment: I am using pandas 1.0.3. How can I check the datetime version? Googled it but cannot find a proper code that shows me the version number

Comment: `datetime` comes built into Python. Which Python version are you using? I was able to run the code above with Python 3.7 and Pandas 0.25.3.